# Best way to find all input elements inside a form using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to find all form elements inside inside a form and trigger a flag on change in the value. Currently I am using the method below. I am not sure if this works or not. But It surely works for: `.find('input[type=text])`

```
$('#form').find('input[type=text], input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox], select, textarea').each(function(){
  $(this).change(function(){
    if( change !== 1 ) change = 1;
  });
})
```

Now I have added multiple elements with the comma. Will this work and is this the best way to do this.

Appreciate all the help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#form').find(':input').each(function(){
  $(this).change(function(){
    if( change !== 1 ) change = 1;
  });
})
```

Check the doc @:

> http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/

Comment: will this select the textarea and select type elements as well?

Comment: Could also just be `$('#form :input')`.

Comment: Yes. Selects all input, textarea, select and button elements.

Comment: I need to make sure that this doesn't catch the change in submit button, button. I am guessing the .change function wouldn't be triggered on button elements anyway.